# how can i achieve a background like in css given this kind of images?

Tags: html, css, frontend, background, background-image

I'm just learning HTML and CSS.So,I was given a design but i don't know how to design the background image part because there are two very large background image.Here's the design
[image: Here's what i wanted to achieve]

and using the following CSS snippet,here's what i achieve

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: url(images/bg-pattern-top.svg) , url(images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg);
    background-color: hsl(185, 75%, 39%);
    background-position: top left, bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;

}
```

[image]

Please can anyone guide me on how to modify my code to get what i want to achieve?The circles image are two different very large SVGs image and I don't know how to make them not to overlap.These SVGs are very large.Their size is 978px by 978px.Here's the inmage of the svg
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So if my first answer didn't work you can try this:

```js
.background {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-top.svg);
}

.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(images/bg-pattern-bottom.svg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="background top"></div>
  <div class="background bottom"></div>

  <div class="content">
    <!-- Your HTML content here -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also you can specify the width and height in the css

This method involves creating two div elements that will act as containers for the background images. These divs will cover the entire viewport, and their positioning will be adjusted using [CSS position properties](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp) to ensure they cover the top and bottom areas respectively.

You will need to adjust the properties of these div elements (background-image, background-size, background-repeat, etc.) based on your design requirements and the dimensions of your SVG images to achieve the desired visual effect.

Comment: Please Sir,I don't want answers only because I  am here to learn.I won't gain anything from you giving me only answers.Please try to justify your answers.

Comment: @AdebimpeAbdulhamidEniola Sorry, I though you just wanted the answer I have modified the answer and add explanation at the end